# Parameterization in adf?

Tags: azure

If we define array type parameters outside all activity then want to apply it in dataset in copy activity in foreach where string type parameters is there then how can we access these parameters ?

Comment: can you please share example code etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you are asking for source dataset. For Sink dataset as well, it will follow same steps but you will have to do the same things in "Sink" tab.
Here, I'm doing it for "Source".

1. Take array as parameter (outside of all activities that means it is a pipeline parameter).

[image: Shows test parameters]

2. Choose "Add dynamic content" [image: Chosen Add dynamic content]
3. Choose pipeline array parameter "test_param", for which "ForEach" activity will run and click finish.
   [image: Dynamic content]
4. Add New source dataset "test_Parquet" using "+" symbol.
   [image: Added source dataset]
5. Go to Source dataset "test_Parquet" -> **Parameters** and add new parameter,<here I've added "param" with datatype String>
   [image: Add dataset parameter]
6. After adding that, return to "Copy activity" and you will see "param (your parameter)" under "**DataSet Properties**":

[image: Parameter]

6. Click on "add dynamic content" and add "pipeline array parameter element" to the dataset parameter value.
   [image: add pipeline parameter]
7. Click on "ForEach iterator -> current item" and click Finish.
   [image: Choose item]

This process will add the pipeline array parameter elements to Copy Activity source dataset.